# Trying to load "font.TTF" results in "error reading file" "file not found"

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to create a game in libgdx, and I want to load a `ttf` font and draw some text in the screen but it does not work on my android device, I get `Unfortunately, game has stopped`. I am using Android Studio as the IDE.
It works on desktop.

This is how I load the font:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"));
```

I get the following error in logcat:

```
03-07 20:41:44.902    9759-9779/com.mygdx.game.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 5345
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: font.ttf (Internal)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Library.newFace(FreeType.java:69)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.<init>(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:106)
            at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:42)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1513)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: font.ttf
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Library.newFace(FreeType.java:69)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.<init>(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:106)
            at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:42)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1513)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

This is where the file is:

[image]

This is my `build.gradle` file
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
... Gdx.files.internal("font.TTF"));
```

The Android filesystem is case sensitive.